# Executing 'ls' all the time? Bash

Tags: bash

Is there a way that I can make a bash window execute "ls" all the time? I am doing another thing on another bash window so I just wanted to see it update every millisecond to see if some files are gone or added.

Comment: If `ls` takes less than a millisecond to run, and if you can read that fast, then yes.  But you can't read that fast!  60 fps is too fast for you to see what's going on.  If you're on Linux, you should look into iNotify.

Comment: How is this a question about programming? SuperUser or unix.stackexchange.com might be a better fit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [watch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/watch) command and have it run every second.

`watch -n 1 ls`

Answer (score 2):

It's as simple as

```
while :; do ls; done
```

However, you'd probably want a short delay so this might be more appropriate:

```
while sleep 1; do ls; done
```

It will pause for 1 second between the `ls` invocations.

You might also find it desirable to clear the screen before calling `ls` such that the terminal doesn't scroll:

```
while sleep 1; do clear && ls; done
```

In any case, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to break the loop.

Comment: Thanks for this. But I think `watch` looks cleaner. So I'll choose AlexMeng's answer but I'm giving thumbs up.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `ls` in a loop. Instead, use [`inotifywait`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait).
It allows you to wait for modification to a file/directory.

This should get you started:

```
inotifywait -m -e CREATE -e DELETE . | {
    #If CREATE is received on stdout, a file is created.
    #If DELETE is received on stdout, a file is deleted.
}
```

It also has options for recursive (`-R`).
`-m` could be skipped, if you want to manually use a bash loop.

Normally, I would use it as this:

```
inotifywait -m -e CREATE -e DELETE . | while read dir operation filename; do
    grep -qi '^CREATE$' <<< "$operation" && echo "file $3 created"
    grep -qi '^CREATE,ISDIR$' <<< "$operation" && echo "directory $3 created"
    grep -qi '^DELETE$' <<< "$operation" && echo "file $3 deleted"
    grep -qi '^DELETE,ISDIR$' <<< "$operation" && echo "directory $3 deleted"
done
```

Note: I am using grep here, but same could be (& should be) done by bash variable comparison. I'm just being lazy to write code for a case insensitive comparison.

Comment: With the caveat that `inotify` doesn't exist for all systems.

Comment: ^^ Agreed... But if it exists, then it is a better solution than `ls` loop. Because, `inotify` uses `select` syscall, AFAIK; thus, keeping CPU free. If it is available, use it. Else, fall back to `ls`.